# phpstorm compile sass minify

Tags: sass, phpstorm

hi i know they compiled the css files with phpstorm but that's what i want

I want it to save as both home.css and home.min.css, but failed. Thank you in advance for your help.
[Sass](https://sass-lang.com/)

```
dist
home.css
home.min.css
home.css.map
```

```
Arguments
--update $FileName$:$ProjectFileDir$\dist\$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css

Output paths to refresh
$ProjectFileDir$\dist\$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css:$ProjectFileDir$\dist\$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css.map
```

Comment: this can't be done using a single tool; if you need _both_ `.css` and `.min.css`, you have to transpile your sass file with Sass and then use some minify tool to compress the generated `.css` files. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2020.3/compressing-css.html for more info

Comment: Why, when sass is compiled, it can generate .map but not .min.css?

Can we generate .css twice at compile time?

Comment: it can generate `min.css` when being run with `--style=compressed`; but it will emit `min.css` only, non-compressed CSS won't be produced. SASS compiler doesn't have an option to produce both `.css` and `.min.css` at the same time

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment.